# what is meant by stochastic drift?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

could anybody define what is meant by stochastic drift?

I *think* I have a rough idea, say on a random walk X(n)= a + X(n-1) + Z(n) where Z(n) are iid zero mean and constant variance, then E[X(n)] = na. Is this stochastic drift?

Many thanks

Comment: The term $Z(n)$ is your stochastic drift term. As it is stated, you have a deterministic drift term also $a$.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_drift) gives a definition:

> stochastic drift is the change of the average value of a stochastic (random) process.

If you look [further down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_drift#Stochastic_drift_in_economics_and_finance) that page, it's clear that the final term in your model is the source of stochastic drift.